# RegEx for matching exactly N number

Tags: c#, .net, regex, model-view-controller

I have the regex working

`[\b\s\n\r\^][1-9][0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}[\b\s]`
 from site  https://regexr.com/

but it's not recognizing first two numbers in following group

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
>   1 2 3 4 - 5 6 7 8

also it should not identify the invalid one.

Valid

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
>   1 2 3 4 - 5 6 7 8
>   12345678
>   1234-1234

INVALID

> 1-18000-55113
>   01234567
>   09581300
>   1234567

Comment: I don't see the right pattern. What are the rules for valid and invalid numbers? [Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%5cd-%5d%29%28%5b1-9-%5d%7c%5b1-9%5d%7b4%7d-%3f%5b1-9%5d%7b4%7d%29%28%3f!%5b%5cd-%5d%29&i=Valid+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+1+2+3+4+-+5+6+7+8+12345678+1234-1234%0d%0a%0d%0aINVALID+1-18000-55113+01234567+09581300+1234567) is a regex that matches all valid and ignores all invalid but I'm sure that this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Valid
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[1 2 3 4 - 5 6 7 8]
[12345678]

[1234-1234]


INVALID
[1-18000-55113]
[01234567]
[09581300]
[1234567]

Comment: sir, please help here, valid should recognize and invalid should ingore

Comment: the rule is --> 8 digit number not start with 0, and it can allow space after each number . and dash after 4 digit.

and invalid is it should not start with 0 and not more than 8 digit . no dahs after  first digit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your samples and looking at your regex attempt, you can use this regex,

```
^[1-9] *(?:\d *){3}(?:- *)?(?:\d *){4}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `[1-9] *` - Starts with a digit 1 to 9 followed by optional space(s)
- `(?:\d *){3}` - Followed by any digit which is followed by optional space(s) and whole of it three times
- `(?:- *)?` - After matching four digits, can optionally be followed by hyphen `-` followed by optional space(s)
- `(?:\d *){4}` - Further followed by four more digits which can optionally be followed by space(s)
- `$` - End of string

**[Regex Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/wz3lVh/1)**

**[Working demo in regexr](https://regexr.com/4dlf3)**

**Edit:**
As mentioned in comments, if you want to find such strings in a larger text, you can use following regex,

```
\b[1-9] *(?:\d *){3}(?:- *)?(?:\d *){3}\d\b
```

**[Regex Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/wz3lVh/2)**

Comment: it works on https://regex101.com/ but somehow I need on https://regexr.com/

Comment: it works on regex101.com but somehow I need on regexr.com – Amol Saraf 23 secs ago    Edit    
could you please try on regexr.com it wont work there :( – Amol Saraf just now    Edit    De

Comment: @AmolSaraf: It works on regexr.com too. It wasn't working because you didn't enable `multiline` mode. I've enabled it there and its [working on regexr.com](https://regexr.com/4dlf3)

Comment: could you please conver the above working regex into format like [\b\s\n\r\^][1-9][0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}[\b\s]


that will be great help sir...

Comment: I am using VBscript code and somehow it does not work with * and $ ... as the field is numeric...

Comment: could you please conver the above working regex into format like [\b\s\n\r\^][1-9][0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}[\b\s] that will be great help sir... – Amol Saraf 1 min ago    Edit    
I am using VBscript code and somehow it does not work with * and $ ... as the field is numeric... – Amol Saraf 23 secs ago    Edit

Comment: Ok, I think you want to find such strings in a bigger text. In that case start/end anchors needs to be replaced with word boundaries. Let me do, just few moments.

Comment: @AmolSaraf: I've updated my answer. You can use this regex [`\b[1-9] *(?:\d *){3}(?:- *)?(?:\d *){3}\d\b`](https://regex101.com/r/wz3lVh/2)